# Bandwidth Limits for App File Downloads

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have an Android app that teaches users Spanish/Russian/Italian. Basically the
app is a series of 10 audio lessons. To keep the app size small, I'm included none of the audio files in the binary (APK) file.

So users are prompted to download each file, one at a time. Can I use ubuntu1 for this purpose?

What if I used 1TB/month of data, is this allowed in the free Ubuntu One service?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One is not a file hosting service, no. If you want to host a download for your project, and your app is open source, you can create a project for it on https://launchpad.net/, create a release, and upload a file to be downloaded for each release.